# 'property' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, ethereum, web3py

So I have am connecting to a contract, and that seems to work fine, I am trying to use this class: web3.personal.Personal from https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.personal.html and I dont seem to understand what i am dong wrong...  when i print(web3.personal.Personal) gives me back a class object but I cant seem to use any functions associated with this class, says I am missing "self" argument

```
contract_abi = my_abi
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(myurl))
myContract = w3.eth.contract(address ,abi)
ref = ref = web3.personal.Personal('web3')
print(ref) #this works   
print(ref.newAccount(password='the-passphrase')) #This crashes

TypeError: newAccount() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
TypeError: 'property' object is not callable
```

Comment: You probably need to *construct* a `Personal`, so `ref = web3.personal.Personal()`.

Comment: instances are represented by `self` and classes are not

Comment: So when I did web3.personal.Personal, I didnt get an error, but when I do web3.personal.Personal() I get an error...

Answer (score 6):

It seems that `web3.personal.Personal` is a class, so in order to create a object you need to say `ref = web3.personal.Personal()`

Please note, classes are often (but not always) written with a capital letter.

Comment: Update: ref = web3.personal.Personal('web3') I need to add 'web3' as an argument, however I can't call functions from this class

Comment: If you say `ref = web3.personal.Personal('web3')` then ref is an object of web3.personal.Personal. So you can call  the functions of the object, not the class. Is it possible that you want to use your `w3` object of class `web3`instead of the `web3` class in order to create `ref`?

Comment: so in the docs, there are methods associated with web3.personal:
https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.personal.html 
web3.personal.importRawKey(self, private_key, passphrase) for example, I am unable to call these methods on ref